# PDFBOX: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?

Tags: java, certificate, pdfbox, digital-signature

I am trying to perform signing using pdfbox. Before calling saveIncrementalForExternalSigning method, I am adding validation information.

```
    public ByteArrayOutputStream addSignature(PDDocument document, PDSignature signature, InputStream inputStream,
                                              SealCSCCredentialOptions cscCredentialOptions, Certificate[] certificateChain, String signatureFormat)
            throws Exception {


        

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ExternalSigningSupport externalSigningSupport = null;
        try {
            externalSigningSupport = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Request ID: {} Error occurred: " + e.getMessage(), LoggerUtils.getFromThreadContext("requestId"));
            throw e;
        }

        CMSSignedData signedData = generateCMSSignedData(certificateChain, externalSigningSupport, inputStream,
                cscCredentialOptions, signatureFormat);

        byte[] cmsSignature = signedData.getEncoded();
        externalSigningSupport.setSignature(cmsSignature);
        
        return outputStream;
    }
```

But I am getting intermittent error while calling `externalSigningSupport = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(outputStream);`
**COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?**

I am getting this error intermittently. sometimes it's giving that error. I am getting successful response in some of the case.

Can someone please help to figure out what I am doing wrong and why I am getting that error intermittently?

Comment: You're likely closing your document or your COSStream before saving. If it happens when saving then open the incomplete result PDF in NOTEPAD++ and look at the end. That's the COSStream that makes the problem.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr as mentioned in code, I am not closing the the document or COSStream. moreover that error is coming intermittently. If I might have closing the document or COSStream, then that error should come every time. Might be gc closing the document. Is there way I can handle that?

Comment: We don't see what you did with the `PDDocument` before calling `addSignature`. Did you add objects from another `PDDocument` to it?

Comment: Another possible explanation is that java somehow loses the document reference, or thinks it does. Make sure you have installed the latest version. jdk8 is at 1.8.0_371.

Comment: Please add more of the stack trace.

Comment: Issue was due to the garbage collection in java. I was creating local object of signature options in one method and was adding it to the document. Since signature option was local object, was getting automatically closed due to garbage collection. I created signature options at root method and close it after all the execution gets completed

Comment: Please answer the question yourself to help others.